# Как настроить сортировку записей в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Записи на странице выводятся следующим образом

```html
<div class="uk-grid uk-grid-collapse vtop">
    <?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $posts = query_posts(array('cat'=>$category_id,'posts_per_page'=>'9','order'=>'DESC','paged'=>$page));?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // если посты есть - запускаем цикл wp ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/loop','product'); // для отображения каждой записи берем шаблон loop.php ?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;?>   
  </div>
```

В строке добавляю поле сортировки, но результата нет

```html
$posts = query_posts(array('cat'=>$category_id,'posts_per_page'=>'9','orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC','paged'=>$page));?>
```

Так же при замене query_posts на get_posts выводится только 1 запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="uk-grid uk-grid-collapse vtop">
    <?php 
        $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

        $args = array( 
            'cat'=>$category_id,
            'posts_per_page'=>'9',
            'orderby' => 'title', 
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged'=>$page );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                get_template_part('template/loop','product');  
            endwhile;
        endif; 
    ?>   
</div>
```